# How to get href value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get href value using jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jquery Test</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a").click(function(event) {
                alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
                var href = $('a').attr('href');
                alert(href);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Care to tell us what exactly didn't work? was the alert empty? did you even get 2 alerts? Any js errors? It's working for me...

Comment: upss ..., sorry. the problem is clear cache

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/t1xs4wo7/

Answer (score 443, accepted):

You need

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Inside a jQuery click handler, the `this` object refers to the element clicked, whereas in your case you're always getting the href for the first `<a>` on the page. This, incidentally, is why your example works but your real code doesn't

Answer (score 19):

It's worth mentioning that

```
$('a').attr('href'); // gets the actual value
$('a').prop('href'); // gets the full URL always
```

Answer (score 18):

You can get current href value by this code:

```
$(this).attr("href");
```

To get href value by ID

```
$("#mylink").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have this html :

```
   <a class ="linkClass" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"> Stack Overflow</a>
```

You can get and display the href attribute with this JS snippet :

```
<script>
    $(".linkClass").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works... Tested in IE8 (don't forget to allow javascript to run if you're testing the file from your computer) and chrome.

Comment: Chrome can suppress the second popup depending on your settings, were you testing in chrome?  If so, comment out your first alert and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

if the page have one `<a>` It Works，but，many `<a>` ,have to use `var href = $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: gives undefined output

Answer (score 0):

```
**Replacing  href attribut value to other** 
 
 <div class="cpt">
   <a href="/ref/ref/testone.html">testoneLink</a>
 </div>

  <div class="test" >
      <a href="/ref/ref/testtwo.html">testtwoLInk</a>
  </div>

 <!--Remove first default Link from href attribut -->
<script>
     Remove first default Link from href attribut
    $(".cpt a").removeAttr("href");
    
    Add  Link to same href attribut
    var testurl= $(".test").find("a").attr("href");
    $(".test a").attr('href', testurl);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html link is like this:

```
<a class ="linkClass" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"> Stack Overflow</a>
```

Then you can access the href in jquery as given below (there is no need to use "a" in href for this)

```
$(".linkClass").on("click",accesshref);

function accesshref()
 {
 var url = $(".linkClass").attr("href");
 //OR
 var url = $(this).attr("href");
}
```