# How to get Google Search API results href values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the simple Google API to display search results. I would like to get the href value of a link on mouseover or click. It is really not important what flavor of javascript is used, I just need to get the user selected href value of the rendered search.

(I need this as I have a webservice that allows users to save links they find of interest.)

I am horrible at client side scripting so I could really use a hand. With the example here I using the default Google AJAX Search API Sample.

[To visually explain I have posted this image.](http://www.thesupermedia.com/test/googlesearch/jquerymouseover2.GIF) (cannot attach)

I have used the link -
[How to get href value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098408/how-to-get-href-value-using-jquery) - for simple reference to no avail. I believe it is due to the way/page render order that the google search results are displayed.

The html source pre render is as follows:

```
    <!--
  copyright (c) 2009 Google inc.
  You are free to copy and use this sample.
  License can be found here: code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#license
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    *  How to do a search that returns the max number of results per page.
    */
    google.load('search', '1');
    function OnLoad() {

      // create a search control
      var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

      // Set the Search Control to get the most number of results
      searchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET);

      // Create 2 searchers and add them to the control
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.BlogSearch());

      // Set the options to draw the control in tabbed mode
      var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();
      drawOptions.setDrawMode(google.search.SearchControl.DRAW_MODE_TABBED);

      // Draw the control onto the page
      searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("content"), drawOptions);

      // Search!
      searchControl.execute("Subaru STI");
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">

    <div id="content">Loading...</div>

  </body>
</html>

The relevent rendered result html source is as follows: 


     <div class="gs-webResult gs-result">
                        <div class="gs-title">
                            <a class="gs-title" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru_Impreza_WRX_STI" target="_blank">
                            <b>Subaru</b> Impreza WRX <b>STI</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a></div>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.
Thanks a million, Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite certain about the Google library that you're using - from what I could tell from a quick search it seems to be deprecated. You might want to link to where you're getting the samples from.

If you just want to extract the `href` on `click` or `mouseover`, you might do this:

```
$('a.gs-title').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked', $(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

This uses jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler to attach this click-handler to every `<a>` element that has the class `gs-title`, even if it gets added to the page later (to do it on `mouseover`, simply change the first argument to `mouseover` instead of `click`). The handler itself does nothing but prevent the default click action (so you'll find that the links do not work) and log the `href` to the console. You can adapt it to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using silverlight to render the output. Your example works for the depreciated Google api using Jquery.

Comment: Pretty sure the `live` function has since been deprecated. IIRC, it's been integrated into `on` via a extra parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two files.

ajax.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
  #container
  {
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 230px;
    background: #5CCCCC;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    display: none;

  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>hello how are you?</p>
    <p>Please run this file with localhost url only else it won't work</p>
    <p>you can double click at any word to get the no of results</p>
    <div id="container"></div>  

    <script>
      var p = $('p');
      p.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>')
      });
      p.click(function(event) {  
      var x=event.pageX;
      var y=event.pageY;
      $("#container").css(
      {
        "top":y+"px",
        "left":x+"px"

      }).fadeIn(500);
      $("#container").text("Loading....");
      var a=event.target.innerHTML;
      $("#container").load("index.php?str="+a+" #resultStats");  //Since number of results are saved in a id named resultStats,using that to filter the content.from google page.
      });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And another file is a .php file from there i am pinging the google server to fetch number of total results.

index.php:

```
<?php
    $str_to_search=$_REQUEST['str'];
    $a=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=define+". $str_to_search);
    echo $a;
?>
```

Remember run both files via php server.