# Extracting Data from Within an XML Tags

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to extract a url from an XML tag using javascript and I was wondering if anyone would know how to do so? In this example, I would be trying to extract 'http://www.google.com'

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.google.com" />
```

I tried extracting data using:

```
data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

but this tag does not have any nodeValue (figures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].getAttribute("href")
```

The href is an attribute instead of a nodevalue. I think the above should return the url.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this: [How to get href value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098408/how-to-get-href-value-using-jquery)

> var href = $(this).attr('href');