# extracting content from href jsoup

Tags: jquery, html

given the following source page :

```html
 < a class="card-click-target id-track-click" data-server-cookie="CAIaHgocEhoKFGNvbS5yb3Zpby5hbmdyeWJpcmRzEAEYAw==" data-uitype="500" href="/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

i have been searching for a while now and cant find the answer . i need to extract the href content from google play source page after searching ann app  , for example if i search angry birds i want to extract from source page  the next text : "/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds"
(my main goal after i get this is to get the description of the app).
thanks for the help !

Comment: doesn't the jquery('selector').attr('href'); helps!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get href value using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098408/how-to-get-href-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(source);
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

    for (Element element : links) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
    }
```

By the way you have a redundant space in the opening tag ("< a"), it also may cause problems.

Comment: thanx !! i added an if statment to check which one of the element array is good for me,and found what i wanted !

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr('href')` in jQuery to achieve this.

Working code snippet below:

```js
var href = $('.card-click-target.id-track-click').attr('href');

alert(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a 
   class="card-click-target id-track-click" 
   data-server-cookie="CAIaHgocEhoKFGNvbS5yb3Zpby5hbmdyeWJpcmRzEAEYAw==" 
   data-uitype="500" 
   href="/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds" 
   aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"
   >
</a>
```