# Jquery get href link

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").each(function(){
        var str=$(this).attr("src");    
        console.log(str);
    });
```

What I want to see is a string that contain "http://mywebsitelinked.com" for example.

Now what the console display is:

```
a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link
accessKey:""
```

And all the other thing contained in a.wooocommerce-LoopProduct-link

Comment: Are you try `attr('href')`?

Comment: Can you please add an example of the markup you are using?

Comment: Where's your HTML code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get href value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098408/how-to-get-href-value-using-jquery)

Comment: if you insert you html it may be a bit easier to understand what you're doing. `src` attribute is an image attribute and you're trying to get href which is an `a` attribute. And you maybe think about something else too :D

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It return the same thing that `$(this).attr("src")` return

Comment: Just solved, I think the problem was console.log(str) not showing the URL but the entire object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$(this).attr("src");
```

try

```
$(this).attr("href");
```

as you are trying to get the `URL` and `URL` is in the `href` attribute of the anchor.

Ex:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('a').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="http://google.com/">Google></a>
```

Comment: I've already tryed this, but it doesn't work and it return the same thing as `$(this).attr("src");`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using link element you have to use

```javascript
$(this).prop("href")` or `$(this).attr("href")
```

or just

```javascript
this.href // (vanilla Javascript, better)
```

Comment: I usually preffer vanilla JS over jQuery :P

Answer (score 0):

try: this will match all the hrefs with mywebsitelinked.com

```
$(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").each(function(){
  var str=$(this).attr("href");
  if(str.match(/mywebsitelinked.com/gi)!=""){
    console.log(str);
  }
});
```