# Can't get the href value of an anchor tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-extension, opera-extension

I'm trying to get the `href` value of an anchor tag using jQuery, but the `this` keyword is not working as expected.

[image: source code]

Here is the result of the code in the console:

[image: devtools console]

---

**The part of the code I have problem with:**

```
$('#container a').click(() => {
    console.log(this);
    let link = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log("from jquery - " + link);
    //chrome.tabs.create({ url: link });
});
```

As you can see, the `this` keyword is pointing on the `window` object.
This code is part of an extension I'm trying to build for Opera.

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098408/how-to-get-href-value-using-jquery

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for people to better help you (and to help those that may come here in the future) you should add your relevant code here instead of posting a link to an image with code.

Comment: This might help you too https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using an arrow function** `() => {..}` instead of a regular function `function () {...}`, that's why your `this` didn't work as you've expected.

So instead of this:

```
$('#container a').click(() => { ... });
```

**Use this:**

```
$('#container a').click(function() { ... });
```

**Your updated code:**

```
$('#container a').click(function () {
    console.log(this);
    let link = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(link);
})
```

**OR with an arrow function:**

```
$('container a').click(event => {
    let link = $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
    console.log(link);
})
```

---

**More on arrow functions:**

- [**Concise article from Wes Bos**](https://wesbos.com/arrow-functions/)
- [**Good video from MPJ**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sQDTgOqh-I)
- [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: You're welcome! Which implementation worked the best for you?

Comment: the one with the function syntax , i really need to read more about the lambda expression, the behavior of it is different from the one i used to

Comment: Nice! **I updated my answer with some useful links** to help you to fully grasp arrow functions in JavaScript. Have fun and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

**This will give you the href value**

```
var href = $('a').attr('href');
```

**Here is a sample to test here:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    var href = $(event.target).attr('href'); //this will give you the href value
    alert(href);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<a href="I'm the href value">this is a test link, click me</a>
```

Comment: the problem is when i use the arrow function the 'this' keyword' point to the window object not the tag that fired the event. i fixed it, thank you for your answer

Comment: this works well until there is more than 1 a in the page.

Comment: the point of my answer was to demonstrate how to get attr value with jquery since this is the title of the question.

Comment: I updated the answer to take the element from the event. so this will work even if there are multiple of the same element

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the arrow function (`() => {}`) use classic function declaration (`function() {}`). Arrow functions don't bind `this` to the current scope.

```
$("#container a").click(function(){
    console.log(this);
    let link = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(link);
})
```

You can learn more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).